# How to make a background overlay image repeat fully CSS?

Tags: css, wordpress, background-image

I have multiple background images on my wordpress site http://casper-creations.com, one is the background image and the other a transparent diagonal line pattern over the top it works fine but it doesn't repeat on the full page if you look carefully on the first page it only seems to go half way down, you can see it clearer on this page http://casper-creations.com/weddings-2/

Here is my css, I have it set to repeat so not quite sure why it isn't repeating the full length of the page...any ideas anyone?

Thanks...

```css
html {
  overflow-y: scroll;
  font-size: 100%;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;
  -ms-text-size-adjust: 100%;
  background: #c2e8eb url(http://casper-creations.com/wp-content/themes/responsive/core/images/bg-cloud.jpg) repeat-x;
}
body {
  font-family: Arial, "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size: 13px;
  line-height: 1.5em;
  background: url(http://casper-creations.com/wp-content/themes/responsive/core/images/bg-diagonal-pattern.png) repeat;
}
```

Comment: Try to use pseudo selector like `::after`, `::before`

Comment: I'm sorry I'm not sure what you mean

Comment: I wouldn't even mind if the both the backgrounds were fixed,which I have tried removing the scroll and setting to fixed on both the body and html but the body but it doesn't work

Comment: Working fine in Chrome for me.

Comment: Isn't perfect, but for demonstration of pseudo selectors `::after` and `::before` is enough. http://jsfiddle.net/choq1bb0/1/

Comment: It doesn't work if you look now it only covers that section

Answer (score 4):

It's because of this fragment of code http://take.ms/Nixqs

```
html, body {
    height: 100%;
}
```

When you set body as 100% width `background-attachment: fixed` image is repeated as long as the height of the body, so only 100% of whole window. Remove it and everything should be ok.

Here is [image with working example](http://take.ms/K8xlFd)

Comment: That would be brilliant if I could find it, it doesn't seem to be in the theme css or my custom css

Comment: There's only this in the theme css and only what I have posted in my custom css

`/* 1.1 Defaults */

html { font-size: 62.5%; background-color: #6e95b6; }
body  { font-size:1.4em; line-height: 1.7142em; color: #777;   }`

Comment: Cool i think i've fixed it, I couldn't find the above so I just added

`html, body {
    height: auto;
}`

And that seemed to fix the problem!

Comment: Actually it didn't but it just seemed to bring it down further, there's a small gap at the bottom

Comment: So You need to oberwrite this - try to płace sth like html, body {height:auto!important} in custom css

Comment: There's still a gap at the bottom

Comment: Your background image will be as long as device screen height with this declaration height:100%

Comment: I can't find that height to remove it

Comment: So I don't know how to help with this bottom gap :( good luck with trying

Answer (score 0):

You are having problem with different heights on body and html. Just and `min-height: 100%;` to body selector.

```
body {
min-height: 100%;
}
```

[image]

Comment: I'm having trouble stretching the body diagonal line background the full length of the page the html cloud background does, I tried adding min-height it didn't work

Comment: I think I found it, you have:

body {
 height: auto !important;
} 

just remove that and it's working, I'm using Google inspector. Rule is in [custom-csss](http://casper-creations.com/?custom-css=1&csblog=1&cscache=6&csrev=103)

Answer (score 0):

If there isn't a way to edit the css I have there is a better way to re-write the css for the body and html tags completely so there is a multiple background with the diagonal lines on top and the cloud underneath

Comment: I gave up and just added the diagonal line to the background itself...never mind...